# Null pointer while inserting in database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I  need to set cookie and  store cookie - key, value and timestamp in MYSQL.

Hence, i have a CookieUtil.java to set(addCookie) and get cookie. Then I created a CookieEntity.java and mapped it with a DAO layer - interface and implementation. I have nullpointer at `int noOfRows = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL,namedParameters);`.
It seems namedParameterJdbcTemplate is null. But I really can't figure out why?

CookieEntity.java

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class EWPCookieEntity {

private String key;
private String value;
private Timestamp timeStamp;
//.... setters and getters
}
```

CookieDao.java interface

```
public boolean saveCookie(CookieEntity reqCookie);
```

CookieDaoImpl.java

```
package com......dao.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com......CookieDao;
import com......CookieEntity;
@Repository
public class CookieDaoImpl implements CookieDao{

@Autowired(required=false)
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

private String FETCH_USER_DETAILS_QUERY = "fetch.user.query";

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CookieDaoImpl.class.getName());

@Override
public boolean saveCookie(CookieEntity reqCookie) {
    String SQL = "insert into cookie_details(KEY, VALUE, TIMESTAMP) VALUES (:key, :value, :timeStamp)";

    Map<String,String > namedParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    namedParameters.put("key", reqCookie.getKey());
    namedParameters.put("value", reqCookie.getValue());
    //namedParameters.put("timeStamp", reqCookie.getTimeStamp());

    int noOfRows = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL,namedParameters);
    System.out.println(noOfRows);
    logger.info("Cookie Details Saved: [ " + reqCookie.toString() + " ]");
    return noOfRows > 0 ? true : false;
}

@Override
public List<CookieEntity> getCookieValue(String key) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public int deleteCookie(String key) {

    return 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void mapFromCookieDetailsResultSet(final CookieEntity cookieEntity, final ResultSet resultSet) {

    try {
        cookieEntity.setKey(resultSet.getString("KEY"));
        cookieEntity.setValue(resultSet.getString("VALUE"));
        cookieEntity.setTimeStamp(resultSet.getTimestamp("TIMESTAMP"));


    } catch (SQLException se) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(
                    "**** Class UserDetailsDaoImpl **** Method mapFromUserDetailsResultSet **** SQLException Occured : "
                            + se.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(
                    "**** Class UserDetailsDaoImpl **** Method mapFromUserDetailsResultSet **** Exception Occured : "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

/**
  * @param namedParameterJdbcTemplate the namedParameterJdbcTemplate to set
  */
 public void setNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
  this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
 }
```

}

My stacktrace is:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SimulatorServlet] in context with   path [/abc] 
      threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception                
      java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
      java.lang.NullPointerException
at com....CookieDaoImpl.saveCookie(CookieDaoImpl.java:36)
at com......LoginController.doLogin(LoginController.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

My root_context.xml

```
<!-- JdbcTemplate -Starts -->
 <bean id = "jdbcTemplate" class =    "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="fetchSize" value = "100"/>
<property name="dataSource" ref = "appDataSource"/>
</bean>

 <!-- JdbcTemplate -Ends -->

 <!-- NamedParameterJdbcTemplate -Starts -->
 <bean id = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class =  "org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- NamedParameterJdbcTemplate -ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<context:annotation-config />` in your `root_context.xml` to get `@Autowired` working.
Or you add `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>` in `root_context.xml` if you plan to use annotations like `@Service`, `@Component` etc. The latter one has the first one already included.